# Unable to compare 2 arrays (case insensitive) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I have stored a list of event_id that contains data regarding that 50 events in a csv file. I have 50 csv files with corresponding event_id with a list of user_id that will attend that event. The list of people that actually attend that event is saved in mysql DB. So, now would like to compare both list to see who actually attended the events. However, the data stored in csv is uppercase while the data in mysql is stored in lowercase.

```
Master Event CSV File
event_id  event_date
001       x/x/2014
002       x/x/2014
003       x/x/2014

50 event csv files (each file is named after the event_id):

CSV file name: 001.csv
user_id   first_name
cust_123       Chris  
cust_234       John
cust_345       David
```

So what I have done so far is loop through the master event csv to get the event_id and with that event_id, I am trying to store the the user list in $data array. Then, I retrieve the list of actual attendance from db in $checkUser. Finally. I use array_intersect to compare the two arrays.

```
$con= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',$username,$password);

//Master CSV File containing all user id and user info
$file_handle = fopen($fileName, "r");

//while loop to loop through Master CSV to get the event id
$i = 0;
while ($i < 50) {

    //Get the event id from CSV Master file
    $file_line = fgetcsv($file_handle , 1024);
    $event_id = $file_line[0];

    //open csv file containing user id for each event   
    $csv_handle = fopen("file.csv", "r");

    //Get list of user_id from csv
    $data = array();
    while($row = fgetcsv($csv_handle)) {
    $data[] = $row[0];
}

    //Get list of user_id from mysql
    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE event_date = ");
    $sql -> execute();
    $checkUser = array();
    while($result = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $checkUser = $result['user_id'];
}

    //Compare 2 arrays for matches
    user_intersect = array_intersect($checkUser, $data);

    $i++;
}

?>
```

I get the following error. Any help would be great.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www...
```

Comment: '$checkUser = ..' means exact value of variable a string in your case.. '$checkUser[] = ..' means add value to array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
$checkUser = $result['user_id'];
```

Even though you declared `$checkUser` as an array before the `while` loop, it is acting as a variable which is getting overwritten on each iteration and thus will contain only the last value from the loop. So it's not an array, but just a variable.

In order to keep it an array, you need to use it as:

```
$checkUser[] = $result['user_id'];
```

The `[]` implies that the current item is being added to the existing array instead of overwriting it.

**EDIT**

In order to work with case insensitive values, you could use [array_map](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$user_intersect = array_intersect(
                     array_map('strtolower', $checkUser), 
                     array_map('strtolower', $data)
                   );
```

Comment: can array_intersect deal with case insensitive data?